# Clear all the fields in infopath on click of a button

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

I have an infopath 2010 form with around 100 controls and i have a requirement to clear all the fields on click of reset button. I have the following options:

1. Clear all the fields on by one (Very Tedious process)
2. Close the forms and open a new form

I am not allowed to write code. Any help in implementing option 2 above is appreciated.

Note: I will be deploying these forms as browser enabled forms to a sharepoint form library.

Comment: Filler or browser? There is a neat trick that works fine in Filler, but not in a browser form.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Filler form, you can try the "Blankem" technique outlined in this post on Infopathdev.com. It involves editing the source files and won't work in a browser form.

http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/t/23486.aspx

There is a sample file attached to Patrick Halstead's first post after the question.

A video with a walk-through is here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rtXm5oOEhI&feature=plcp

The rule that is used cannot be applied to a browser form, since `the Blankem technique involves using a Set Value destination XPath that is not a simple node path, and not something that the InfoPath designer would let you select.  While InfoPath filler will allow you to still use the form under these conditions, SharePoint will not allow it.` (source: [comment from Jimmy Rishe at another thread at Infopathdev.com](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/24555/84926.aspx))

If you are using a browser form, you will need to clear the fields with individual actions in a rule.

Comment: It is a browser form unfortunately. If you have something that works on a browser form do let me know!

Answer (score 0):

try to copy full shema to string (while it is clear) and then in button event replace shema

```
http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/08/clear-reset-fields-infopath-3-lines-code/
```

it may help you